# How to check user logged in with ExpressJS and Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I want to check if user logged in correctly, redirect him to `Home Page`, else redirect to `Log In Page`. I have written the code below but It works for even not correct login info :

```
Users.findOne({
  username: req.body.Username,
  password: req.body.Password
}).then(eactOne => {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant add code sorry, i write on phone.

```
Users.findOne({
  username: req.body.Username
}).then(eachOne => {
  if (eachOne) {
    if (eachOne.password == req.body.Password) {
      res.redirect('/');
    } else {
      res.send('Wrong');
    }
  } else {
    res.send('User not found');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Great help, Just for reminding small mistake in checking password, It should be `user.password` and I edited that.